# Why emitted events of livewire is not triggered?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

In laravel 7 learning livewire/livewire 1.3  I encountered that emitted
events are not always triggered

I created component with command

```
php artisan make:livewire hostel/hostelsHomepageSpotlight
```

and simplifying the code I do not see alert of event.
In app/Http/Livewire/Hostel/HostelsHomepageSpotlight.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Hostel;

use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Config;

use App\Hostel;
use App\HostelImage;
use App\library\CheckValueType;
use App\Settings;
use Livewire\Component;

class HostelsHomepageSpotlight extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {

        $hostels     = [];
        $current_page= 1;
        $hostel_rows_count = Hostel
            ::getByStatus('A')
            ->count();

        $this->emit('hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened', [ 'mode'=> 'hostels_homepage_spotlight', 'current_page'=>$current_page, 'hostel_rows_count'=>$hostel_rows_count ] ); // EMIT EVENT

        return view('livewire.hostel.hostels-homepage-spotlight', [
            'hostelsDataRows' => $hostels,
            'hostel_rows_count'=> $hostel_rows_count,
            'current_page'=> $current_page,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in resources/views/livewire/hostel/hostels-homepage-spotlight.blade.php:

```
<div>
    
    <h1>hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened</h1>

</div>   

<script>
    // If to uncomment line below I see  alert
    // alert( 'resources/views/livewire/hostel/hostels-homepage-spotlight.blade.php::' )
    window.livewire.on('hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened', data => {
        // I DO NOT SEE ALERT BELOW ANYWAY
        alert( 'hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened::' )
        console.log('facility_opened data::')
        console.log(data)
        // alertsInit(data.mode)
        // lazyImagesInit("img.lazy_image")
    })
</script>
```

Why event is not triggered ? Is there is a way to debug it ?

**UPDATED # 2:**
I know the rule about wrapping div(without any class or styles definitions).
Have I also to remove JS code ?

I tried to move all JS code in resources/js/app.js :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('./bootstrap');

var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks")
Turbolinks.start()

// If to uncomment the line below I see it
// alert( '::resources/js/app.js' )
window.livewire.on('hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened', data => {
// I do not see this alert
    alert( 'hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened::' )
    console.log('facility_opened data::')
    console.log(data)
    // alertsInit(data.mode)
    // lazyImagesInit("img.lazy_image")
})
```

and in my resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" xmlns:livewire="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Laravel:Livewire</title>
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    
    
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/lazyload.js') }}"></script>   
    
    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
    @livewireScripts
    
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app/app_funcs.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<body class="text-center">

<div class="flexbox-parent page_container " id="page_content">
    <header class="flexbox-item header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
               ...
            </nav>

    </header>
    
    <main class="flexbox-item fill-area content flexbox-item-grow">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    
    <footer class="flexbox-item footer  ml-3 mr-3">
        ...
        <p class="m-2">copyright_text</p>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my code is nit triggered anywat!
I suppose that is valid structure of my app as app.js AFTER    @livewireStyles
and  @livewireScripts

**UPDATED # 3:**

I tried and that does not work. I have login form :

```
<article class="page_content_container">

   ...    
    <form class="form-login" wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <input
            wire:model.lazy="form.email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            class="form-control editable_field"
            placeholder="Your email address"
            autocomplete=off
        >
    </form>
   ...    
    
</article> <!-- page_content_container -->
{{--@push('scripts')--}}
    <script>
        $("#email").focus();
    </script>
{{--@endpush--}}
```

When @push/@endpush are commented as on lines above it works ok and focus is set to  email input.
But if to uncomment these 2 lines focus is not set.

I modified my resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Laravel:Livewire</title>
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    
    
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
    

    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/lazyload.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    
    @livewireScripts
    @stack('scripts')
    
    
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app/app_funcs.js') }}"></script>
```

app.js - is first as bootstrap and jquery are included there...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Livewire expects components wrapped by a div element.

Sample:
< div>
Your content...
</ div>

What I am saying is that I am not sure you can include javascript in your Livewire blade. Try by moving it out to your app.js file and see if it works because the rest looks good.

I remember having trouble just because the blade’s first line was a html comment, instead of

So, always, first line of your livewire blade must be < div>, and last line </ div>

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please look at UPDATED # 2:

Comment: Not exactly. Livewire component requires a single root tag. It can be `<script>`,  `<div>` or any other as long as it is one.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write script under livewire blade try this way. in your master layout put under   @livewireScripts

```
@stack('scripts')
```

Now you can push scripts in this stack from your livewire blade file like this:

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
// some js code 

</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Please, look at UPDATED # 3

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** It makes sense why in your case it does NOT work. You should NOT emit the event in the RENDER function IFF you want to listen for it in the same view that is about to be rendered. In simple words for your case, the emit happens before the view loads, thus, by the moment your view is ready, it will be a 'bit' late to listen to it, you lost it! :-)

Solution: put the JS (the window.livewire.on... ) one step outside so it will be already ready by the moment you emit the event in the render.

In simple words, place the JS code in the **scripts** section of the parent file, the file you include the following

```
@livewire('hostel.hostels-homepage-spotlight')
```

P.S. When you are dealing with livewire, to listen for an event or fire one,
do not forget to wrap it in the document ready, i.e.,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    livewire.emit('event_foo', 'foooo');
});
```

Thus, your spotlight PARENT page should look something like this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        window.livewire.on('hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened', data => {
            alert( 'hostelsHomepageSpotlightOpened::' )
            console.log('facility_opened data::')
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both components live in the same page:

"Livewire components can communicate with each other through a global event system. As long as two Livewire components are living on the same page, they can communicate using events and listeners."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).